# Ordering $k$ distinguishable items and $n-k$ non-distinguishable items

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

Suppose I have a total of $n$ items, $k$ distinguishable items $x_1,\ldots,x_k$ and $n-k$ non distinguishable items, $o$. How many ways are they to order all the items in a line?

I know that I have a total of $n!$ ways to order all the items in a line, but since the $o$'s cannot be distinguished, I need to reduce this amount by some factor. How can I know what the factor is? At first I thought about the binomial coefficient, but the results I got didn't make sense to my needs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See, first you can permute the entire lot of $n$ in $n!$ ways

Now in any such arrangement, since you can't distinguish between the $n-k$ identical items,
*remove* their permutations by dividing by $(n-k)!$, thus $\dfrac{n!}{(n-k)!}$ ways.

Answer (score 2):

**true blue anil** has explained how to find the reduction factor.

Alternatively, you can first choose $n-k$ places in the line for the indistinguishable objects, and then arrange the $k$ distinguishable items in the $k$ remaining positions. There are $\binom{n}{n-k}$ ways to perform the first task and $k!$ ways to perform the second task, so there are

$$\binom{n}{n-k}k!=\frac{n!k!}{(n-k)!k!}=\frac{n!}{(n-k)!}$$

distinguishable arrangements.